# Center dot within viewable container with overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to center the dot within the viewable container overflow, as you can see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yuc8nzdb/143/)

When clicking the first dot 1 to 3, they are working as intended sticking to the top, and starting the 4th and 5th they should adjust top distance so it will center to the container, and clicking 6th, 7th ,8th, should stay at bottom.

The example of course is not working when I increase the total dot number let say 9 or 10 dots. I can't get the correct math formula, any idea?

Many Thanks.

```js
const ul = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0];
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list li');
const total = 5;
const offset = total / 2;
const circleTotalHeight = 40;

const totalViewable = 5;
const totalHeight = circleTotalHeight * list.length;
const totalViewableHeight = total * circleTotalHeight;
const limitTopOffset = totalViewableHeight - totalHeight; // -120
const halfViewableCount = Math.ceil(totalViewable / 2); //3
const halfTotalCount = Math.ceil(list.length / 2); //4
const centerViewablePx = 160;

let activeIndex = 0;
let nthActiveIndex = activeIndex + 1;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, (li) => {
  li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let data = e.target.getAttribute("data-number");
    const prevElement = `[data-number="${activeIndex}"]`;
    const nextElement = `[data-number="${data}"]`;

    ul.querySelector(nextElement).style.color = '#FFF';
    ul.querySelector(prevElement).style.color = '#000';

    nthActiveIndex = parseInt(data) + 1;
    var nthActiveOffset = nthActiveIndex - halfViewableCount;
    if (data < halfTotalCount && data < halfViewableCount) {
      ul.style.top = '0';
    } else if (data > halfTotalCount && data > halfViewableCount) {
      ul.style.top = `${limitTopOffset}px`;
    } else {
      let midTopOffset = 0;
      if (data < halfTotalCount) {
        midTopOffset = (nthActiveIndex * circleTotalHeight) / 2;
      } else {
        midTopOffset = (nthActiveIndex * circleTotalHeight) - 160;
      }

      const dotContainerTopValue = midTopOffset + limitTopOffset;
      //alert(midTopOffset);
      if (dotContainerTopValue >= 0) {
        ul.style.top = '0';
      } else {
        ul.style.top = `${dotContainerTopValue}px`;
      }
    }

    activeIndex = data;
  });
})
```

```css
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.list li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
}
.list-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #42b549;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li data-number="0">1</li>
    <li data-number="1">2</li>
    <li data-number="2">3</li>
    <li data-number="3">4</li>
    <li data-number="4">5</li>
    <li data-number="5">6</li>
    <li data-number="6">7</li>
    <li data-number="7">8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so onclick of 6,7,8 you want to move 1 position down?

Comment: @NullPointer No, the example is already working as intended but the js code I kinda hardcoded, for 8 dots, clicking on 4th, 5th will move to center as shown in the fiddle. Problem is when if let say I want have 9 or 10 dots, the code in the fiddle is incorrect to behave like when I have 8 dots. Need to find a correct math to make calculation css top. [here][1]  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/yuc8nzdb/146/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, just to share [here](http://jsfiddle.net/archie_lee/yuc8nzdb/180/) . I hope dont miss anything.

```
const ul = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0];
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list li');
const total = 5;
const offset = total / 2;
const circleTotalHeight = 30;

const totalViewable = 5;
const totalHeight = circleTotalHeight * list.length;
const totalViewableHeight = totalViewable * circleTotalHeight;
const limitTopOffset = totalViewableHeight - totalHeight; // -120
const halfViewableCount = totalViewable / 2; //2.5
const halfTotalCount = Math.ceil(list.length / 2); //4
const diffTotalAndView = list.length - totalViewable; // 3


let activeIndex = 0;
let nthActiveIndex = activeIndex + 1;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, (li) => {
  li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let data = e.target.getAttribute("data-number");
    const prevElement = `[data-number="${activeIndex}"]`;
    const nextElement = `[data-number="${data}"]`;

    ul.querySelector(nextElement).style.color = '#FFF';
    ul.querySelector(prevElement).style.color = '#000';

    nthActiveIndex = parseInt(data) + 1;
    var nthActiveOffset = nthActiveIndex - halfViewableCount;
    var nthOffset = Math.floor(nthActiveIndex - halfViewableCount);

    if (nthOffset >= 0) {

      //console.log(nthOffset);
      if (nthOffset < diffTotalAndView) {
        var topDistance = -1 * (nthOffset * circleTotalHeight);
        ul.style.top = `${topDistance}px`;
      } else {
        ul.style.top = `${limitTopOffset}px`;
      }

    } else {
      ul.style.top = '0';
    }

    activeIndex = data;
  });
})
```